# URL Rewrite Rules in Admin

Tags: url, url-rewrite

I apologize if this is a duplicate request someplace else, but I could not find an easy way to locate it if it exists, so here we go.

I want a simple breakdown how to use the fields in the URL rewrite tool, none of the answers I see give a clear cut simple answer (maybe layman terms are needed to help).

Hopefully others can find this useful as well.

**Fields used in the form:**

**Type:** Custom
ID Path: ? - (best way to do this?)

**Request Path:** ? (is the old url slug such as /earrings/cubic-zircon/bella-gold?)

**Target Path:** ? - (is the new url path?)

**Redirect:** No - Yes (simple logic tells me - Yes?)

**Description:** ? (is this a note relating to why you redirected, internal purposes?)

Thank you for your help in advance on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Type**

   `Custom` is the only rewrite type you can create via backend. If you select `Product` or `Category`, you can select an existing item which populates some of the fields as a convenience but sets the type to `Custom` anyway.
2. **Store**

   Selects the store (view) your rewrite is intended for.
3. **ID Path** [(influenced by respectively stolen from Marius)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75463/22860)

   This is just a unique identifier for the URL rewrite. It has no impact on the rewrite logic. Its purpose is to identify rewrites programmatically – if you intend to do so.

   For example, product page URLs use `product/{product_id}` for their id path. Your module might use id paths of the form `my_entity_type/{my_entity_id}` so you can easily access them later.

   Eventually, a rewrite will work even with a nonsensical id path as long as it's unique per store (view).
4. **Request Path**

   This is the path of the original request made by the client/browser marked **bold** in the following example that is to be rewritten - leading slash omitted:
   https://magento.example.com/**path/to/old/product.html**
5. **Target Path**

   This is the path you want your visitors to see instead – marked bold in the following example: https://magento.example.com/**path/to/new/site.html**. This *can* be an external URL.
6. **Redirect**

   You have three options here: no redirect at all, temporary (302) or permanent (301). If you don't want a redirect but rather an internal rewrite of the request – which does a silent rewrite invisible to the user –, go with 'No'. 301 and 302 both send a response with the new location back to the browser which then makes a new request to the given URL, the difference between 301 and 302 being mainly SEO iirc.
7. **Description**

   This is purely for internal purposes so you can remember why you made this entry initially – or for any other note related or fully unrelated to this specific rewrite.